# Transitive models of $V≠L$ within L

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $V=L$. Can there be transitive models of $ZFC+V≠L$?

Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFC. If $x\in M$, then $x\in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ because $V=L$, but it's not evident to me that $\alpha\in M$.

Such an $M$ would necessarily have to be a set, since the only inner model is $L$ itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, transitive models inside $L$ can be very non-$L$-ish.

Specifically, recall **Shoenfield absoluteness**. Since "$T$ has a countable transitive model" is $\Sigma^1_2$,$^*$ by applying Downwards Lowenheim-Skolem in $V$ we have that whenever $T$ is a theory with a transitive set model in $V$ then $T$ has a countable transitive model in $L$.

So, for example, if $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ + "There is a proper class of supercompacts" has a transitive model, then it has a constructible transitive model, despite the fact that of course that theory is *highly* incompatible with the axiom of constructibility for both large cardinal and combinatorial reasons.

- It may help, visualization-wise, to consider e.g. $L_{\omega^2}(\mathbb{R}^L)$. This is a transitive set contained in $L$ of height $\omega^2$ but containing all constructible reals - basically, it's "short and wide" in a way which makes it very different from any level of $L$. Now that's sort of a bad example since it's "informationally" equivalent to the better-behaved $L_{\omega_1^L}$ - each $L_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ is represented by a real in $L_{\omega^2}(\mathbb{R}^L)$ and can be "decoded" in a definable way - but it's a good first taste of how the particular shape of the levels of $L$, rather than their mere constructibility, constrains their behavior.

---

EDIT: There's another theorem which is relevant here. It gets a weaker conclusion than Shoenfield, but is quite different and interesting:

> **(Barwise)** Every countable model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ has an end extension which is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$.

See [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/a-new-proof-of-the-barwise-extension-theorem/). Of course, that end extension will probably be ill-founded - that's why Barwise's theorem doesn't prove $\mathsf{V=L}$ outright. Incidentally, the picture at that blogpost is quite nice on its own - note the added **width**, in addition to height, per the comment about the shape of levels of $L$ in the previous section. Barwise's theorem does not give us a *top* extension.

Barwise's theorem lets us transfer *consistency* results: if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a transitive model of $T$" is consistent then so is $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ + "There is a transitive model of $T$." More generally, note that end extensions preserve internal transitivity satisfaction: if $M\models\mathsf{ZF}$, $A$ and $T$ are in $A$, $M$ thinks $T$ is a theory and $A$ is a transitive set satisfying $T$, and $N$ is an end extension of $M$ (perhaps one satisfying $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$!), then $N$ also thinks that $A$ is a transitive model of the theory $T$.

---

$^*$OK, that's not strictly true: rather, it's $\Sigma^1_2$ *relative to $T$*. So really all we can conclude is that every $\{\in\}$-theory *which is in $L$* which has a transitive model in $V$ also has one in $L$.

A good example of how this can play out is to consider the following. Let $T_0=\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "$0^\sharp$ exists," and let $T_1$ be $T_0$ + axioms correctly stating each bit of $0^\sharp$. Now per the above (under reasonable hypotheses) $T_0$ has a transitive model in $L$. On the other hand, $T_1$ definitely **won't**: a transitive model of $T_1$ has to compute $0^\sharp$ correctly, which $L$ can't. But this is fine, since $T_1$ *itself* computes $0^\sharp$: $T_1\not\in L$ so we can't apply Shoenfield.

Comment: That's slick, thanks!

Comment: @Reveillark On the grounds that I can't leave well enough alone, I've added some details; feel free to revert if that makes the answer less helpful.

Comment: I'd upvote it twice if I could. To be absolutely sure, you want $T\in L$ for the Shoenfield argument to go through? Also, if you'd entertain a slightly unrelated follow up: my original question was motivated by trying to show that $L_\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is the second $\xi$ with $L_\xi\models ZFC$, provided one exists) satisfied "All transitive models of $ZFC$ have the same countable height." Any chance you could shed some light on that?

Comment: @Reveillark Yes, we do need $T\in L$ to apply Shoenfield: Shoenfield only applies to $\Sigma^1_2$ sentences *with parameters from the smaller model*, and $T$ is a parameter in "$T$ has a countable transitive model." So we do need $T\in L$ (and my $T_0/T_1$ example shows how this can break down if we drop this assumption).

Comment: Re: your motivating question, think about the $M\leadsto L^M$ construction. If $M\in L_\alpha$ and $L_\alpha\models$ "$M$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$," then $L_\alpha$ also thinks $L^M$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$. So the heights of the transitive models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in $L_\alpha$ coincide with the heights of transitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ in $L_\alpha$. And per condensation, each of those literally **is** an $L_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$, for which (by definition of $\alpha$) there is only one possibility: the minimal height of a transitive model at all.

Comment: Lovely, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Let me add something to Noah's nice answer. If there are transitive set models of set theory, then there are such models of $V=L$, and therefore there is  a countable $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a model (by the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem and condensation). Since $L_\alpha$ is countable, for any forcing poset $\mathbb P\in L_\alpha$ there are (in $L$) $\mathbb P$-generics $g$ over $L_\alpha$. Except for trivial cases, the resulting models $L_\alpha[g]$ all satisfy $V\ne L$ (although they all live in $L$).

This is actually a useful observation. Jensen exploits to great advantage a version of it in his proof of the theorem that for any countable sequence $\langle \alpha_\nu:\nu<\delta\rangle$ of countable admissible ordinals there is a real $x$ such that the $\alpha_\nu$ are precisely the first $\delta$ admissible ordinals over $x$.

It also shows up in other situations. For instance, in certain recursive definitions of Suslin trees in $L$, at certain key limit ordinals $\delta$ the construction chooses how to continue the partial tree $T_\delta$ built so far by picking a branch generic for $T_\delta$ over a model $L_\alpha$ whose $\omega_1$ is $\delta$.

Comment: No, you don't. I just wanted to emphasize that you can work on $L$, but I kept saying it throughout the paragraph anyway. I rewrote the paragraph.